# Getting the difference between two mirrored rotations in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I have two example objects in Unity structured as follows:

```
EmptyGameObject1: scale(-1, 1, 1)
- Child1: rotation(-4, 167, 179)

EmptyGameObject2: scale(1, -1, -1)
- Child2: rotation(-1, -10, 0)
```

Now I want to get the difference between the euler angles of the childs considering the scale of its parent. Vector3.Distance returns a quite high value, but I see that the rotation of the childs is very similar in the scene view.

I know that a negative scale of the parent mirrors the child object - but 
what does it mathematically do to the rotation?

How can I calculate this rotation difference in unity for x, y and z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that `var rotation1 = Child1.transform.rotation;` and `var rotation2 = Child2.transform.rotation;` (we're working in world space, right?). We want to find a rotation (let's call it `difference`) from Child1 to Child2 such that `rotation1 * difference == rotation2`. This means that we can find it simply by calculating `var difference = rotation2 * Quaternion.Inverse(rotation1);`. Now that we know the rotation, we can just access it's Euler angles property to determine the x, y and z angles: `difference.eulerAngles.x` and so on.

Comment: Glad to help. Quaternions can be confusing if you try to operate on their component values, but working with quaternion on quaternion operations can be much easier. It's always tempting to use Euler angles instead, because they seem much more intuitive, but in a lot of edge cases Euler angles break while quaternions work perfectly.